# Use of lsof Command

Tags: lsof

When I open a file in a Python Program

```
sptxt = open('output.txt','w')
```

And then run following:

```
i@raspberrypi:~/Watson $ lsof /home/pi/Watson/output.txt
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
python3.7 16665   pi    6w   REG  179,2        0 645827 /home/pi/Watson/output.txt
```

If I just open output.txt via a text editor and run same command as above i get no result.

Why?
Is there any way of determining if it was opened by the text editor?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the text editor isn't holding the file open.
The longer answer is that a text editor is usually doing things with a bit more finesse than one might assume.

Let's look at the humble `vim` editor.

For preparation, create a file called `demo.txt` and add a couple of lines.

```
Now is the time
for all good men
```

Now use `strace` to see what `vi` is doing:

```
strace -frt -o myfile.txt vi demo.txt
```

Add a new line to the middle of the file, save and exit.

Here's what the key part of the `strace` output looks like:

```
...
15850      0.000037 unlink("demo.txt~") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
15850 (1)  0.000034 rename("demo.txt", "demo.txt~") = 0
15850 (2)  0.000055 open("demo.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644) = 3
15850 (3)  0.000044 write(3, "Now is the time\nadding a new lin"..., 51) = 51
15850      0.000042 fsync(3)            = 0
15850      0.003511 stat("demo.txt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=51, ...}) = 0
15850      0.000039 stat("demo.txt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=51, ...}) = 0
15850 (4)  0.000033 close(3)            = 0
15850 (5)  0.000029 chmod("demo.txt", 0100644) = 0
15850      0.000037 setxattr("demo.txt", "system.posix_acl_access", "\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x04\x00\x04\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff \x00\x04\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff", 28, 0) = 0
15850      0.000091 write(1, " 3L, 51C written", 16) = 16
15850      0.000040 lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET) = 0
15850      0.000029 write(4, "b0VIM 7.4\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\274\267\25_\324\35\6\0\352=\0\0myuser"..., 4096) = 4096
15850      0.000040 stat("/home/myuser/demo.txt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=51, ...}) = 0
15850 (6)  0.000046 unlink("demo.txt~") = 0
...
```

See what `vim` is doing here, in very quick succession at time of save:

1. Renaming the file to a backup file with trailing tilde (`demo.txt~`)
2. Opening `demo.txt` in write mode as file descriptor 3
3. Writing the new modified text.
4. Closing the file (FD 3)
5. Performing `chmod` and such on the new version of the file.
6. Removing the scratch file.

All of these steps are done very quickly, only when the "write file" command is given.
You can edit a file in `vim` and modify the file in a separate process, and `vim` won't do anything about it until the time you try to save the file, at which point it will warn you.

Other editors are likely doing similar things. You can use `strace` to see what kind of system calls they are making and correlate that with what you see in `lsof`.